# Is there a Hyper-V virtual machine client for XP? Linux? Mac?

Tags: hyper-v, thin-client

Is there a Hyper-V virtual machine client for XP? Linux? Mac?
I'm aware that we could VNC or RDP into the virtual machine but the problem is if the VM is not running or is suspend the end user can't start it and IT needs to get involved.

I guess what I'm looking for is something like VMconnect.exe that runs on xp or linux. 
Or, If I am totally barking up the wrong tree let me know. ;-)

Comment: to answer my own question: It is very possible to write your own client! Yes! check out this link: http://blogs.msdn.com/taylorb/archive/2010/05/18/writing-your-own-vmconnect-app-web-interface-for-vm-console-access-to-hyper-v-vm-s.aspx

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no official Hyper-V client for Windows XP, and definately not for Mac or Linux. I can't find the link to the KB, but the only way to access the console of a Hyper-V machine is from the server itself or from a Windows 7/Vista machine.

I've seen the occasional link flying around for http://www.utharam.com but I've never tried it, but it might suit your needs and/or budget.

Comment: while vmconnect.exe works pretty nice on win7/vista, it doesn't really seem like an end user client tool. Doesn't this seem like an oversight? or don't i get hyper-v? ;-)

Comment: I hadn't previously heard of Utharam, but it sounds like what he's asking for. (+1)

Comment: if utharam is like other remote control consolidation programs, you need to install vmconnect.exe seperately. let me know if otherwise. because of this you can't run it on linux, xpe, ce, mac.

Comment: @matt, they claim to run on XP but as I mentioned I've no idea as I've never had a need to use it.

Answer (score 1):

No. If you need console access from any OS other than Windows 6.x, you may find that Hyper-V is not your best option.  VirtualBox, for example, can provide RDP access to the console of each virtual machine.  This is separate from any RDP service provided *by* the VM.  With Hyper-V, the only way to access the console is via the server itself, or via the Windows 6.x Remote Server Administration Tools.

Comment: seems like a big oversight from Hyper-v

Comment: I would venture that it is intentional.  Microsoft wants to encourage enterprises to upgrade workstations from Windows XP to Windows 6.1, and providing backward-compatible tools has the opposite effect.  Similarly, they have a vested interest in discouraging the use of Linux and Mac OS.

Answer (score 0):

You can access virtual machine consoles using freerdp. An Open Source RDP client.

Check out: http://www.cloudbase.it/using-freerdp-to-connect-to-the-hyper-v-console

Combine that with some powershell management tools and you have everything you need to manage virtual hosts :-)